# Does HttpServer handle the same request twice?

Tags: dart

Trying to set up a simple Dart [HttpServer](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpServer.html):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 80).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      request.response.write('Hello, world.');
      request.response.close();
      print(new DateTime.now());
      print(request.connectionInfo.remoteAddress);
      print(request.method);
      print(request.headers.toString());
      print("--------------");      
    });
  });

  print("listing....");

}
```

When hitting localhost from a browser (Chrome), it appears as if the incoming request is handled *twice*:

```
listing....
2013-11-07 15:19:24.478
InternetAddress('127.0.0.1', IP_V4)
GET
host: localhost:80
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
--------------
2013-11-07 15:19:24.554
InternetAddress('127.0.0.1', IP_V4)
GET
host: localhost:80
connection: keep-alive
accept: */*
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
--------------
```

Those two requests look almost identical, except for the `accept` header. Doesn't look like the browser is firing up the request twice:

[image]

So, why does the request get handled twice?

EDIT: Dart SDK version 0.8.10.6_r30036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *output* what is requested (the `url` member of the request instance) and that is the difference between the two requests.

The first request requests the file you try to open, probably `/`. The second request is issued internally by the browser and requests `favicon.ico` to display the icon in the address bar / tab title.

Comment: Aaah. Indeed. And Chrome doesn't display the favicon.ico request in the network tab. :( Thanks!